# how to open and edit a dat file which is a database?

Tags: android, database

I know there are many different ways to open specific dat file if you know the type of dat.
I would like to open and edit the dat files which are database here. http://code.google.com/p/android-traditional-chinese-ime/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fres%2Fraw
Which software can open this?

Comment: what kind of database is that?

Comment: I am not sure so I have asked here and posted the resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are an effectively infinite number of file formats which all use the `.dat` extension.

That being said, these files appear to be Java serialized objects, so you should be able to read them in using an `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: But how to have a whole view of the file and also to edit it? If I use ObjectInputStream, can I output it as a whole not just some strings?

Comment: Depends entirely on what the actual objects being stored are, which I haven't looked at. Write a little test program to pull them in and take a look. As far as editing it goes, there's no way to do that in place; you'd have to write out a new file (using ObjectOutputStream).